# Wifi has no internet Access

Tags: cyanogenmod, wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, oneplus-one

I just install a new router and save its settings to default. I connected Wifi to my Windows 7 laptop successfully and have internet connection. But device with Lollipop says the Wifi has no internet access and shows an exclamatory mark. I tried to change Ip from DHCP to static but it not helped. Please help me out.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the internet? The exclamation mark will show, when your device didn't connect to one of the Google servers on that connection.

Comment: Yes.But no internet connection